# Dice tracker and roll probability percentage

Tags: probability, dice

I have a dice tracker that graphs the combined roll of 2 fair six sided dice (numbers 2 through 12). I want to display the variance percentage that the current number is over/under as a positive/negative percentage. How would I do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to show:

1. One way to do is to compute what the expected value would be of such a roll and then contrast the current draw with that expected value as a percentage deviation.
2. Another approach is to compute a rolling average and show how the rolling average approaches the expected value as the throws increase.

Comment: Right now I'm taking the numbers roll count (ie 7 has been rolled 3 times) and dividing by the total roll count and then minus the probability to get the difference. Is this correct?